# How can I import .reg files into a custom location?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have a .reg file which I wish to explore using the Registry Editor as part of a registry hive. For this, I have to import it. However, neither the Registry Editor nor reg.exe offer a way to specify an import location.

For example, I'd like to import my .reg file into `HKLM\TempHive`, so if it contains `HKLM\System\Foobar`, the new key would be under `HKLM\TempHive\HKLM\System\Foobar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either *import* a [registry file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly or *load* a [registry hive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but not vice-versa. While registry files are human-readable text files, registry hives are binary files, and are handled differently.

If you want to convert a `.reg` file to a registry hive, you have to import it first, and then export it as hive using either `regedit` or `reg /save`.

As a workaround, you could change the base path inside the registry file to e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Temp`, and then remember to delete the key when you're done.

### Further reading

- [About the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516/en-us)
- [reg - Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx)